Recognizability of a substitution implies aperiodicity
Is there a good reference, aside from the book of "Tilings and Patterns" by Grunbaum and Shephard, on the fact that recognizability\unique-composition of a tiling implies aperiodicity? I unfortunately can't access this reference, but I have not found any other written explanation on this implication that I fully understood.
I believe that the argument relies on de-substitution of a fixed point of the substitution, but I have not found where the explicit argument is written clearly. Is there anyone who knows of where this explanation is written?

Later Edit:
I am trying to make more sense of a comment by Solomyak in Nonperiodicity Implies Unique Composition for
Self-Similar Translationally Finite Tilings, where he talks about a well-known "folklore" theorem. Solomyak mentions that unique composition is the analog to recognizability, so I think this is alludes to what I am asking about.

If x is n-periodic for the shift, then any preimage of x in a recognizable substitution is at most n-periodic for the shift. In the primitive case, this is immediately a contradiction. For non-primitive substitutions, this is possible, e.g. $\tau(1) = 010, \tau(0) = 0$ has periodic points in its subshift, but is recognizable (or what are your definitions?)

@VilleSalo I am interested in the primitive case. I understood that aperiodicity implies recognizability, which is a result by Mosse. But going by a remark in Boris Solomyak's work, I understood that there should be a converse direction.

Yes, the converse I proved in my comment.

As Ville says, the converse is the easy direction. It's conceptually easier to prove the contrapositive (periodicity implies non-recognisable). I gave a bit more detail on the proof in this old answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530892/why-does-this-aperiodicity-proof-work/2531674#2531674
